# multi jackson date format config in springboot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, date-format, jackson2

In my springboot applicaiton, serialization date format pattern = 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss', and I want to deserialization date format pattern = 'yyyy-MM-dd'.

In the `application.yml`:

```yaml
spring:
  jackson:
    timezone: "GMT+8"
    date-format: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
```

But, This is global and works for both serialization and deserialization.

What should I do?

Comment: You should configure it manually on the getter and setter of the field itself.

Comment: What do you mean you want 'yyyy-MM-dd'? That you want a LocalDate as object instead of a LocalDateTime? Deserializing will not get any format, it will be populated into an object.

Comment: I know that @JsonFormat can be configured on bean properties, is there a similar global configuration method. Because I have many bean objects